# And operator on two rank-1 tensorflow tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two rank-1 tensors, one of them contains X floats, the other is one-hot, also with X entries.

I want to create a new rank-1 tensor, with a single element: the float in the first tensor at the index where the one-hot vector is equal to 1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like tf.boolean_mask is what you're looking for: 
  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask